# Promise rejected with non-error warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

Error: `h1.js:25 Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]`

Not entirely sure why, would love help understanding the error and what's causing it. Still learning Promises and AJAX so help greatly appreciated! (For example, as I write this I also think it's a bit redundant to have a Promise wrapping an ajax object, but honestly I don't know how to re-write it otherwise)

```
var logisticsModule = (function() {
  return {
    initialize: function() {
      dateTimeFxns.getReservedDates.then(
        // success
        function(reserved_dates) {
          console.log("success with value = " + reserved_dates)
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log("error with value = " + error)
        }
      )
    }
  }
})();

var dateTimeFxns = {
  getReservedDates: new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({ 
      // some url & data
    })
    .done(function(result) {
      resolve(result)
    }
    .fail(function(error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  logisticsModule.initialize();
})
```

**UPDATE warning message persists when I have the `.fail` as:**

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  reject(new Error(errorThrown))
})
```

Comment: do console.log(error); the error is saying that error is not an object of type Error

Comment: You get a string, but it is best to create an `Error` object. So in your reject function do `reject(new Error(error))`. That's an additional issue apart from what the error actually is. Advantage: Stack trace will be available on the `Error` object.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason it hasn't fixed my problem, see update

Comment: The extension that's throwing this in Chrome is Honey, I just un-installed it. If you're the author, I hope you fix it soon.

Answer (score 15):

This just means that the error that was thrown is not an `instanceof Error`. For example, the following is not an error, but I can throw it because... well... you can throw anything in JavaScript.

```
throw 42;
```

Which gives us a wonderful `uncaught exception: 42`.

To throw an *actual* error, use an `Error`:

```
throw new Error('An actual error');
```

Now in your specific case, you need to pass the error that jQuery supplies, which isn't the first argument it passes. It gives you a string, so wrap it in an error...

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  reject(new Error(errorThrown));
}
```

Comment: I made the code this: `.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      reject(new Error(errorThrown)) })` and am still getting the error. I'm also a bit confused... if errorThrown is from the ajax itself shouldn't it already be formatted for me as an Error Object?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, as I write this I also think it's a bit redundant to have a Promise wrapping an ajax object, but honestly I don't know how to re-write it otherwise

You could define a function that returns the AJAX object, which stated in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), returns an object that uses the JavaScript Promise interface.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).

Here is a code example of how to implement such a function. I am using the [Random User API](https://randomuser.me/) for example data.

```js
function getRandomUser() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .fail(error => console.error(error));
}

// getRandomUser's return value is a Promise like object, which we can chain onto
getRandomUser()
.then(
  function(random_user) {
    console.log("success with value = ", random_user)
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("error with value = ", error)
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```